# Intern Runner JSON Report generation

Tags: intern

I am using intern Runner for creating reports. I have successfully created default reports but I want to create report in JSON format. Can anyone guide me ?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a built-in JSON reporter at this time, so the quickest way to get JSON output would be to write one. Luckily, reporters are very simple. For example, check out the [Console reporter](https://github.com/theintern/intern/blob/master/lib/reporters/Console.js). Basically, a reporter is just a class with method names corresponding to Intern reporter events (like `suiteEnd` and `testPass`). As those methods are called, the reporter creates its report. A JSON reporter could just add results to a `report` object and then write that to a file in a `runEnd` handler.